# Spring injection of userdetailsservice in security config class fails

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am new to spring security and i am trying to configure it using java but when i try to inject a UserDetailsService into a security config class i get a 404 error page but when i inject it into a controller the injection works. am using spring version 4.1.6 and spring security 4.0.0

here is my security config class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("loginService")
UserDetailsService loginService; //THIS IS THE POINT OF FAILURE

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/")
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/userlist")
            .failureUrl("/")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .permitAll();
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    /*auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");*/
    auth.userDetailsService(loginService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {

            web
              .ignoring()
                 .antMatchers("/resources/**");

          }


@Bean
public Md5PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
    Md5PasswordEncoder encoder = new Md5PasswordEncoder();
    return encoder;
}
}
```

This is the UserDetailsService class

```
@Service("loginService")
public class LoginService implements UserDetailsService{

@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository;

@Transactional
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    SiteUser user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

    Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<SimpleGrantedAuthority>();
     SimpleGrantedAuthority userAuthority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER");
     SimpleGrantedAuthority adminAuthority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN");
    User u = null;
    if(user == null) 
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No such User: " + username);
    else
    {

        if (user.getRole().equals("USER"))
               authorities.add(userAuthority);

        else if (user.getRole().equals("ADMIN")) 
        {
               authorities.add(userAuthority);
               authorities.add(adminAuthority);
        }
        u = new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), authorities);
    }

    return u;
}

}
```

The rest of the project is available
[here](https://github.com/vinnieashken/Test/)

Comment: It would help if you posted the stack trace you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to add
     @ComponentScan("com.ashken.*")
 on top of the securityconfig class

Answer (score 0):

I've found that it is less troublesome to simply register your implementation of UserDetailsService as a bean in SecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository;

@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
  return new UserDetailsService() {

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

      SiteUser user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

      Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<SimpleGrantedAuthority>();
      SimpleGrantedAuthority userAuthority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER");
      SimpleGrantedAuthority adminAuthority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN");
      User u = null;
      if(user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No such User: " + username);
      } else {

        if (user.getRole().equals("USER")) {
          authorities.add(userAuthority);
        } else if (user.getRole().equals("ADMIN")) {
          authorities.add(userAuthority);
          authorities.add(adminAuthority);
        }
        u = new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), authorities);
      }

      return u;
    }

  };
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/")
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/userlist")
            .failureUrl("/")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .permitAll();
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    /*auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");*/
    auth.userDetailsService(loginService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {

            web
              .ignoring()
                 .antMatchers("/resources/**");

          }


@Bean
public Md5PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
    Md5PasswordEncoder encoder = new Md5PasswordEncoder();
    return encoder;
}
}
```

Comment: It seems  that whenever i inject anything in that security config class it just fails. autowiring the userRepository leads to the same begaviour as with autowiring the userdetailsservice.

Comment: there is no stack trace. i just get a http status 404 page.